# Entity Framework and MongoClient with Task

Tags: c#, mongodb, entity-framework, task

In a console application I'm starting from a list and open multiple tasks to handle them like:

```
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { Elabor(el.Take(1000).ToList(), listLogDequeues); }));
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { Elabor(el.Skip(1000).Take(1000).ToList(), listLogDequeues); }));
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => { Elabor(el.Skip(2000).Take(1000).ToList(), listLogDequeues); }));
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

`el` and `ListLogDequeue` is a `ConcurrentBag<T>` and inside the function an integer is incremented safely using `Interlocked.Add`.

This allow me to run three/four tasks and perform operations, but inside Elabor  is used Entity Framework and MongoClient, as two repos injected with Ninject in my console application Main. Each function build and use it's context, but I don't get if and how concurrency and thread safety can hurt here.

EF:

```
public OutAnag GetAnagById(string id)
{
    try
    {
        using (var c = new Context())
        {
            return c.Anag.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Mongo:

```
    public bool SetElab(string guid)
    {
        Context dbContext = new Context();

        try
        {
            var filter = Builders<Anag>.Filter.Where(m => m.Guid == guid);
            var update = Builders<Anag>.Update.Set(m => m.DataElaborazione, DateTime.Now);
            var options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<Anag>();
            dbContext.Anag.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```